# Nexus 7 system update notification

Tags: notifications

My Nexus 7 permanently displays a 'system update downloaded. Touch to install' notification' that I can't seem to clear. I've touched the notification to install but am just taken to apps. Can anyone help me get rid of this notification, please? Many thanks.

Comment: Did you try going to Settings->About Phone->System Update and trying to update the phone from there?

Comment: Is your Nexus 7 rooted?

Answer (score -2):

Download the updated image and manually flash it instead. That is what I did with mine.